# Laravel 6 - Lógica al reves

Tags: laravel-6

Se que la pregunta suena loca, pero...

Tengo una función que analiza un el ancho/alto de una imagen y lo compara con el ancho/alto de unos límites previamente establecidos.

Para esto, el código que uso es el siguiente

```php
$ancho = DB::table('imagenes__descripcions')
                ->select('ancho')
                ->where('id' , '=', $plantilla_id)
                ->get();

        $ancho_array = [$ancho];

        //dd($ancho_array);

        $alto = DB::table('imagenes__descripcions')
                ->select('alto')
                ->where('id' , '=', $plantilla_id)
                ->get();

        $alto_array = [$alto];

        //ahora obtenemos los ancho y alto de la imagen

        $file = $_FILES["img"]['tmp_name'];
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

        if($width != "$ancho_array[0]" || $height != " $alto_array[0]"){
                
                $alerta = "La imagen no cumple con los estandares, la imagen debe ser " . $ancho . " x " . $alto . "y tu imagen es " . $width . " x " . $height;
                dd($alerta);
        }

        $success = "success, la imagen es " . $width . " x " . $height . " y cumple con los limites de " . $ancho . " x " . $alto;
        dd($success);
```

Ahora, con esto se ve que si la imagen NO es del tamaño de los limites, tira el error y en caso de que lo fuere hace el success, ¿cierto?...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los parámetros son exactamente iguales y envia el error, pero si cambio el "!=" por un "=="...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yyyy esto me confunde...¿Acaso la logica es lo opuesto a lo que yo recuerdo? ¿O estoy haciendo algo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás comparando número con cadena y en el alto estás agregando un espacio adicional:

```
    if($width != "$ancho_array[0]" || $height != " $alto_array[0]"){

            $alerta = "La imagen no cumple con los estandares, la imagen debe ser " . $ancho . " x " . $alto . "y tu imagen es " . $width . " x " . $height;
            dd($alerta);
    }
```

Quita las comillas, compara solo números y no debería haber problema, de hecho creo que las variables usadas para la comparación no son las correctas, deberían ser $ancho y $alto, respectivamente, en lugar de $ancho_array[0] y $alto_array[0]:

```
    if($width != $ancho || $height != $alto){

            $alerta = "La imagen no cumple con los estandares, la imagen debe ser " . $ancho . " x " . $alto . "y tu imagen es " . $width . " x " . $height;
            dd($alerta);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! De hecho hice algo parecido pero con: $ancho->ancho (lo mismo con alto) y funcionó de manera perfecta.

Comment: A la respuesta de @Triby agregaría el hacer cast de los tipos de datos, por mantener la seguridad.